# Alinhar à esquerda e diminuir a distância entre controles com bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Veja a imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe que o primeiro label(CNPJ) está muito distante da margem e o mais importante para mim. A distância entre o label e o controle está muito grande e que a distância entre o label OS e o controle input do CNPJ está grande também. Como eu resolvo essa questão: Meu código abaixo.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css" />

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <link href="~/Content/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

................
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtCnpj1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">CNPJ:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtCnpj1" placeholder="Digite o Cnpj">
                    </div>
                    <label for="txtOS" class="col-sm-2 control-label">OS:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-small" id="txtOS" placeholder="Digite o numero da OS">
                    </div>
                    <input id="btnPesquisar" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Pesquisar" onclick=" return MontaAgendamento();" />
                </div>
            </form>
............
```

Comment: Não percebi bem como queres que fique.

Comment: Que fique bem próximo da margem. Eu mudei para col-sm-1, e ganhei assim, algum espaço, ou seja, está próximo ao que eu quero. Acho que o caminho será diminuir esse espaço. O que não sei o que é: col-sm-*, col-md-*, col-lg-* e etc... Como eu trabalho dentro do grid que o bootstrap monta, fazendo deslocamento para qualquer lado. Falta isso.

Comment: tenta usar o `pull-left` na classe do label CNPJ. Ou no div do form-group.

Answer (score 1):

As classes col-xs, col-sm, col-md, col-lg são utilizadas para especificar qual o tamanho que a coluna deverá assumir em cada resolução.

Explicando:

.col-xs-(tamanho da coluna) : Especifica qual será o tamanho do coluna em celulares

.col-sm-(tamanho da coluna) : Especifica qual será o tamanho do coluna em tablets

.col-md-(tamanho da coluna) : Especifica qual será o tamanho do coluna em desktops

.col-lg-(tamanho da coluna) : Especifica qual será o tamanho do coluna em monitores maiores que desktops normais.

Agora para que as classes funcionem corretamente você precisa englobar seu código em outras duas divs que servem para definir o tamanho total do grid.

No seu caso o código ficaria assim:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
       <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <label for="txtCnpj1" class="col-md-2 control-label">CNPJ:</label>
         <div class="col-md-10">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtCnpj1" placeholder="Digite o Cnpj">
        </div>
     </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="txtOS" class="col-md-2 control-label">OS:</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
         <input type="text" class="form-control input-small" id="txtOS" placeholder="Digite o numero da OS">
       </div>
       </div>
       <input id="btnPesquisar" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Pesquisar" onclick=" return MontaAgendamento();" />
     </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Esse código irá alinhar o bloco de CNPJ e de OS como você quer, para os outros campos basta seguir como está no código acima. E para maiores informações sobre como funciona o sistema de grid do bootstrap acesse http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid